# How to connect via PowerShell cmdlet Connect-AzAccount

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to connect via PowerShell cmdlet Connect-AzAccount on my Desktop

but it failed I couldn't find the article describe clearly how to connect the Azure portal via PowerShell

Please help

Comment: Hi @Abdulghani, You just need to run `Connect-AzAccount` in powershell .Please refer [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-5.1.0).If you are  still facing any issue please share us the error.

Comment: Yes ther is an error,

Connect-AzAccount : The term 'Connect-AzAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-AzAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-AzAccount:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 3):

You  need to install Az module.

Please run the following cmdlets to install and import the module,

```
Install-Module Az
Import-Module Az
```

Now you can run the `Connect-AzAccount` cmdlet without any issue